# Filter strings in a list for for numbers at specific index

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am filtering through a text project of rearranging addresses from other texts. I have a list I am calling rest. Each list is a different address and description on a new line of text.

I want to copy all words from the first index, up until the zip code, but the text words have some house numbers as the first index, and I want to stop from the list not just at any numeric value, but specially one that is a number and not the first index. How would I iterate through these lists?

```
rest = ["town name", "state", "98420", "description"],["222", "street", "state", "98420", "description"], ["town name", "state", "94820", "description"]

addr = []
for i in rest:
    addr.append(rest[i])
    if len(i) == 5:
     # append and end list
```

These are just examples, my real lists look like
rest = ['lilypad', 'CA', '94820', 'beautiful', 'green', 'city'], ['1800', 'turtle', 'Ave', 'CA', '94820', 'tropical']

and I want the list to be addr = ['lilypad,' 'CA', 94820'], ['1800', 'turtle', 'Ave', 'CA', '94820']

I am filtering through several lines of addresses, but the numbers and names are mixed up.

Comment: I guess I can iterate through the lists for a numeric value and string must be 5 characters in length

Comment: This python code has indentation errors.  What is the point of the indented list on line 2 of the code?  It is not assigned to any variable.  It's just hanging out all by itself.  Why is `for i in rest:` indented?  etc etc.  Please fix these indentation errors so that we can actually **run** this code.

Comment: Also, none of the data in the list is numeric, so `if i.isnumeric()` will never be true...

Comment: I edited it to show what my list of strings look like.

Comment: "How would I iterate through these lists?" well, apparently you already know how to get at the list, and you already know how to write a loop, so it's not clear to me what the problem is. Do you know how to skip the first element when looping over them? Or else where exactly do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```py
rest = ["town name", "state", "98420", "description"],["222", "street", "state", "98420", "description"], ["town name", "state", "94820", "description"]

addr = []
for i in rest:
    addr_i = i[:1] # don't check the first string
    for j in i[1:]:
        addr_i.append(j)
        if j.isnumeric(): break # stop if numeric
    addr.append(addr_i)
```

resulting `addr`:

```py
[['town name', 'state', '98420'], ['222', 'street', 'state', '98420'], ['town name', 'state', '94820']]
```

---

##### EDIT :

> *can you help me get the rest of the list into a new list called serv?*

You could use [`enumerate`](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) and do something like

```py
rest = ["town name", "state", "98420", "description"],["222", "street", "state", "98420", "description"], ["town name", "state", "94820", "description"]

addr, serv = [], []
for i in rest:
    addr_i = i[:1] # don't check the first string
    for n, j in enumerate(i[1:],1):
        addr_i.append(j)
        if j.isnumeric(): 
            serv.append(i[n+1:]) # rest of the strings
            break # stop if numeric
    else: serv.append([]) ## no numerics found
    addr.append(addr_i)
```

> ```py
> addr = [['town name', 'state', '98420'], ['222', 'street', 'state', '98420'], ['town name', 'state', '94820']]
> serv = [['description'], ['description'], ['description']]
> ```

Comment: This solves it, thank you so much for the help and the break down too!

Comment: By chance can you help me get the rest of the list into a new list called serv?  serv (short for services) Like the all of the descriptions, I decided to iterate through the  list in reverse and want to stop at the zip code again, but this time, not include it.

Comment: @JackieMarie see my edit. hope it helps